# Validate email using regex that ends with @pin.edu.sh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

so I've been having a rough time on how can I properly use regex, I'm creating a register form wherein the email used must consist `@pin.edu.sh`. so if the user decided to use for example.

`johndoe@gmail.com`, it will not accept, but if the user uses `johndoe@pin.edu.sh` it will be accepted.

I tried using this, but I think I got it wrong.

`/^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+@pin+[.]+edu+[.]+sh$/`

So I'm using react-hook-form for validation.

```
const validEmail = /^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+@pin+[.]+edu+[.]+sh$/

<TextField   
    variant="outlined"
    name="email"
    label="Email"
    required
    fullWidth
    type="email"
    autoComplete='email'
    {...register('email', {required: "Required", pattern: {value: validEmail, message:     "It should be a valid email address!" }})}
    error={!!errors?.email}
    helperText={errors?.email ?errors.email.message: null}
/>
```

Additional:

So for example, if the user tried to register using a different email that doesn't contain `@pin.edu.sh`

for example, `johnsmith@gmail.com`, My register form will show that the email used is not allowed.

but if the user used an email like this. `johnsmith@pin.edu.sh`, then the register form will accept the account.

Comment: So you want to design a regex that takes both `johndoe@pin.edu.sh` and `johndoe@gmail.com`, correct?

Comment: Will you want anything specific from `@pin.edu.ph` or something similar to `@sahu.org.com`?

Comment: And please include that and above information in your question for a better understanding.

Comment: @DSDmark, my bad. What I meant to say is `@pin.edu.sh`

Comment: In that case, you could try this `/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@pin\.edu\.sh$/` but im not sure about that.

Comment: You can try below regex
**^[\w.+\-]+@pin\.edu\.sh$**
or
**^[a-z0-9](\.?[a-z0-9])+@pin\.edu\.sh$**
And you can also check both the regex from this website: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 3):

You can use the code below to fix the issue in bash.

```
email="johndoe@pin.edu.sh" 
if [[ $email =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@pin\.edu\.sh$ ]]; then
echo "Valid email address." else
echo "Invalid email address." 
fi
```

Comment: `I'm using react-hook-form for validation`

Answer (score 2):

You can try below regex

```
^[\w.+\-]+@pin\.edu\.sh$
```

or

```
^[a-z0-9](\.?[a-z0-9])+@pin\.edu\.sh$
```

And you can also check both the regex from this website:

> https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

I think Benze provided a valuable output above, you can also use this for PY. I'm what was provided to you previously should fix it.

```
import re
email = "example@pin.edu.sh"
if re.search(r"@pin\.edu\.sh$", email):
print("valid email")
else:
print("invalid email")
```